# Links on Github-Pages while using a theme

Tags: javascript, html, markdown, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

So i'm building a small website on gh-pages and i'm using a gh-pages markdown theme. 
To implement a navigation bar i've slightly modified the "default.html" file to also feature a bar inside the header.
Now i'd like to link or navigate between pages while still keeping the theme, header and such. But when using 
`<a href="anotherPage.md">Another Page</a>`
it reloads an entire new blank page.
But when first visiting `https://myPersonalPage.github.io/` it loads up just fine and it does load index.md properly.

So in short, I'd like to change the content of a gh-page without changing the header and I don't know how.

In the default.html file my links look like this:

```
<!-- HEADER -->
<div id="header_wrap" class="outer">
    <header class="inner">
        <h1 id="project_title">MyProjects</h1>
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.md">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="projects.md">PROJECTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutMe.md">ABOUT ME</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

And in the default.html file the content-load looks like this:

```
<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<div id="main_content_wrap" class="outer">
    <section id="main_content" class="inner">
        {{ content }}
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, i figured it out. Instead of projects.md, i had to link on projects.html and everything works out fine.